# Floodfill Algorithm without any Seed?

Tags: algorithm, flood-fill

I was wondering if it would be possible to write a Floodfill Algorithm just with the parameter of the area, which somewhere has a bordered sub-area that needs to be filled. I can't really think of a way to implement it. Does anyone have an idea ?

Comment: Can you clarify which data structure you have in mind, how borders are represented, ...etc?

Comment: No I mean a parameter for a function. Like a function that gets a grid, lets say 100x100, with entries 0, with a sub-area somewhere surrounded by ones. Would it be possible to find that area and change all the cells inside of it to ones as well ? How would you do it ?

Comment: It's quite possible - if I understand your question, you want to select a area and to do the `floodfill`?  Can you show us where you got stuck so that people can help?

Answer (score 0):

You mean like paper.io?

1. You can start the flood fill from *outside* the grid (or every non-boundary cell adjacent to an outer edge).  That will fill everything that is not inside a bounded area.
2. Then invert the filled region and subtract the boundary to get everything that is inside the bounded areas.